# Fixing wall after pipes froze

Tags: walls

A few weeks ago my pipes froze to my washing machine. Being inside the wall, I removed some drywall and thawed them out.

Upon fixing the problem, I also noticed R-11 insulation in the walls. I am replacing this with R-15 and also foam board behind the pipes.

I have read space is needed between the foam board and the exterior tar paper.

There is not enough room behind the pipes, and I can’t move them without tearing into more drywall.

Is it okay to just install the foam board without spacing behind it?

*EDIT: As an added note, the pipes froze because someone cut a hole in the wall for the dryer vent and did not seal the hole around the vent pipe. I put in a new pipe and sealed it with spray foam.

Comment: I don't understand the mechanics of why you would need a gap. My understanding is that such a gap is more for rafter cavities. Even then, though, that's only with air permeable insulation like fiberglass batts. Can you provide a link or two? And the plan is to only use the foam board at pipe locations for better protection?

Comment: The plan is to place the foam board along the entire space between the studs behind the pipes. Then place fiberglass batts except where the pipes are to allow heat from the house to keep them from freezing. In case the foam board isn’t sufficient.

Comment: What are the layers in your wall assembly?  I'd expect from outside to inside for it to be:  Siding / WRB (tar paper?) / sheathing / 2x4 / drywall.  Your batt insulation is in the 2x4 cavities and you want to put the foam board against the sheathing in those cavities?

Comment: From outside to inside, it’s brick, some sort of sheathing, tar paper. Then, it was R11 fiberglass batt insulation, then drywall. With pipes insulated from inside by the insulation. With no insulation between the pipes and tar paper.

Comment: As an added note, the pipes froze because someone cut a hole in the wall for the dryer vent and did not seal the hole around the vent pipe. I put in a new pipe and sealed it with spray foam.

Comment: Based on the information in your question and the comments, I think your approach is sound.  Insulate the outside of the wall to prevent heat from escaping.  And allow heat from the room to warm the pipes.  And you don't need an air gap with the foam board.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the answers in the comment to it.

Comment: Adding thicker insulation isn't always the answer. If the walls are 2x4s and you pack out one side with rigid foam and then add R15, you'll condense the batt insulation which limits its ability to actually insulate.

Comment: But the batt insulation pretty much maintains its same R-per-inch characteristic, even when compressed.  The loss of insulating capability is because you have less inches of insulation.

Comment: Total depth is about 5.5 inches. There are furring boards on the 2x4s to allow the drywall to line up with the 2x6 base plate. I used half inch foam board.

Total R value will end up being 18 after I install the batt insulation.

I am replacing the copper pipes with Pex and replacing the old valves for the washing machine. Those are hard to close and one is leaking.

Thank you to everyone for your comments. These really helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the answer to this question is, I don't need space between the foam and the tar paper. Which is what I ended up doing. Wish I could share photos, but my iPhone pics are too large.